# A suspected Windows audio driver interrupt issue

Tags: windows, audio, video, media-player, interrupts

I have a projector connected to my PC via HDMI, which receives 1920x1080 59.94 Hz.

The projector has a frame interpolation feature, but to run it completely smoothly it needs all frames to arrive in very strict timeframes and without interruptions or duplicates. That is, for 59.94/60 Hz it is about 16.66 ms.

When I play a 24 fps movie with a 2.0 channel audio track, frame interpolation desyncs happen very rarely, but still do. The more channels the audio track being played has, the more freezes I get on my projector image. That is, 5.1 or 7.1 audio tracks drive the interpolator completely mad (not always though, but the correlation is very clear).

Of course, when I play a video without audio, the image is completely smooth.

So, I have come up with the idea that it is caused by audio interrupts. Some people told me that Realtek audio drivers (which I use) were very interrupt-heavy.

What can I do to force my system to send frames in fixed timeframes? Can I solve this with software or do I need a dedicated sound card?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're outputting through HDMI, usually Windows will use Microsoft's audio codec, not Realtek, not all PCs do though, but if it does, then this isn't Realtek's issue. Check the codec (Realtek High Definition Audio or High Definition Audio Device) and whichever one is the issue. Realtek has been having bad issue such as removing the internal speakers of laptops because faulty driver updates, so it's extremely possible it's Realtek's drivers. See if there's a High Definition Audio Device if it is using Realtek. Click the arrow by the device's name (IF IT IS Realtek), and see if there is High Definition Audio Device. I've experienced the laptop speakers gone issue until Windows 10 fixed it itself, so be careful with drivers.

Comment: I have already removed Realtek and now I am using Microsoft drivers. I am getting the same issue though. There was a High Definition Audio Device with Realtek, and there is one with Microsoft.

Comment: Try both. If neither work, make sure the HDMI you are using doesn't have a short in it or your PC needs new drivers for the video output completely. But if nothing works, your laptop/PC may be faulty with the video/audio output. Has there been any harsh pulls on the HDMI slot? Has there been any bends to the HDMI while in the slot? Have you tried a different HDMI?

Comment: As I said, the issue depends on the number of audio channels, and is completely absent while playing a movie with no audio tracks.

Comment: Any luck so far?